# How to set the location of a JWindow below the textfield when the frame is being drag?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, intellij-idea

I am making an autocomplete project(just like Google). I have a jtextfield in my frame and whenever I type something to that field, a JWindow will appear below the textfield and that window is coming from another class.

Now the problem is how could I make the window always appear below the textfield whenever I drag the frame?

Any help would be much appreciated.. Thanks...

Comment: again, what exactly is the problem? If you coded the location of the window correctly, it will pop up at the correct location relative to the textField, independent of the location of the frame. Or do you mean to keep it open and stuck _while_ dragging?

Comment: keep it open and stuck while dragging

Comment: thanks for the clarification - you are aware that it's _not_ default behaviour (f.i. in google - the dropdown closes while dragging)

Comment: what do you mean in google that the dropdown closes while dragging?granting it closes while dragging.but in my case when i drag my application to different position, the window remains in the previous position on the screen.how can i make it appear below  the position where my textfield is even when i drag my frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for manually set `Locatio`n on the screen, you have to define something as `private Point location;` and `getLocation` from desired `JComponent`, don't forget dealyed show for Show Top-Level Container into `invokeLater();`

for example

```
public void showWindow() {   
    window.setVisible(false);
    location = myTextField.getLocationOnScreen();
    int x = location.x;
    int y = location.y;
    window.setLocation(x - 20, y - 20);
    Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
             window.setVisible(true);
         }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
 }
```

Comment: where should i put this?is this from the jwindow or where my textfield is?

Comment: @Mikel pot that to the void (@see edit), then you will call only voidMane, that would be easiest of ways for you

Answer (score 3):

Use `SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen()/convertPointFromScreen()` pass `JTextField's` position and get coordinates on screen for the `JWindow`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well, you're trying to do a JTextfield which propose a list of suggestions when the user enters some text.

I used this by the past: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm

It needs a bit of refactoring but your problem is what I said, it will help you solve it much more easily (and elegantly)!

To use the example:

```
Java2sAutoTextField textField = new Java2sAutoTextField(
   Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Value 1","Value 2"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a JWindow for that but a JComboBox instead of the TextField.
JWindow's are designed to be toplevel windows ...

Comment: -yeah you right but I want to try it using a JWindow if it is possible. As of now, my only problem is when I drag the frame, the JWindow left on its original position.