# Java: Popup not always visible

Tags: java, swing

I use a Popup to display an update progress. I put a semi-transparent panel above the main window for effect. In far the most cases the Popup is visible but on some computers it's not. It seems to be related to specific computers. Does anyone know a solution or have a better way to implement this?

```
//Disable main components
tabs.setEnabledAt(0, false);
tabs.setEnabledAt(1, false);
comPorts_CB.setEnabled(false);
getinfo_B.setEnabled(false);
//Add effect panel
pop_effect_panel = new JPanel();
pop_effect_panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 192));
pop_effect_panel.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
pop_effect_panel.setLayout(null);
pop_effect_panel.setOpaque(true);
getContentPane().add(pop_effect_panel);
getContentPane().setComponentZOrder(pop_effect_panel, 0);
getContentPane().setEnabled(false);
pop_effect_panel.invalidate();
//Create pop-up panel
pop_panel = new JPanel();
pop_panel.setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
pop_panel.setSize(300, 300);
pop_panel.setLayout(null);
pop_panel.setOpaque(true);
pop_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
pop_progress_TA = new NonSelectableTextArea();
pop_progress_TA.setBounds(2, 2, 296, 268);
pop_progress_TA.setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
pop_panel.add(pop_progress_TA);
pop_progress_bar = new JProgressBar();
pop_progress_bar.setBounds(1, 270, 240, 28);
pop_progress_bar.setValue(0);
pop_progress_bar.setStringPainted(true);
pop_progress_bar.setString("");
pop_panel.add(pop_progress_bar);
pop_ok_B = new JButton("OK");
pop_ok_B.setBounds(241, 270, 57, 28);
pop_ok_B.setEnabled(false);
pop_panel.add(pop_ok_B);
final Popup popup = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(getContentPane(), pop_panel, 100, 250);
popup.show();
pop_ok_B.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        popup.hide();
        //Remove effect panel
        getContentPane().remove(pop_effect_panel);
        getContentPane().validate();
        //Enable main components
        tabs.setEnabledAt(0, true);
        tabs.setEnabledAt(1, true);
        comPorts_CB.setEnabled(true);
        getinfo_B.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
pop_progress_TA.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Comment: BTW 1) Don't use `setLayout(null)`.  Learn how to use layouts. 2) Do consider posting an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) rather than uncompilable code snippets.

Comment: Not related to your problem: Please learn [Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) to make your code more readable. `pop_ok_B` is not how you should name variables.

Comment: Points taken! (It's my first Java app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider that would be better look for/using un-decorated Modal [JDialog or JWindow](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) (by defalut un-decorated) instead of JPopup

Comment: Is it possible to lock it in place over my application (it's an applet) and not show the title bar etc.?

Comment: Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I've implemented using a JWindow, but how do I set the location depend on the applet location. If I select the browser window the JWindow disappears behind the browser window. Is my only option to setAlwaysOnTop(true)?

Comment: @thomas.fogh more in this thread 1) locations on the screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306073/how-to-set-the-location-of-a-jwindow-below-the-textfield-when-the-frame-is-being/7306229#7306229 2) you can setModal(true) if you required actions just from this window, if not then setAlwaysOnTop(true) is good too

Comment: I've set the JWindow owner to the browser frame, and I have almost the behavior I want, except that the JWindow is still visible when I switch between tabs in the browser. Can I had a Listener to let me know if my applet is no longer visible?

Comment: hmmm no idea, maybe better would be start a new question about this specific problem, maybe someone knows answer to your question

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that:

- The progress dialog is created and updated on the EDT.
- The long running task is completed off the EDT.

Comment: *"I've done both.."*  (Pointedly)  An SSCCE would make that obvious.